# How to merge two partitions in gparted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have installed ubuntu and I guess it gave itself a ~15gb partition. Windows still had 1tb. I finally formated the windows partition, or at least a part of it. I want to get the unallocated space on /dev/sda and merge into /dev/nvme0n1

Here are screenshots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/76oy0.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: No. If you look in the picture, my two partitions are separated...

Comment: nvme0n1 and sda are different devices.. Partitions are a way to divide a large space/drive (thru partition table) into smaller parts (partitions), but partition tables do not span drives (unless it's handled by another layer of firmware/software; be it RAID, LVM etc). `gparted` will work with a single drive at a time as it works at the partition table level.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if you don't bother install Ubuntu again, I mean that system is new as out of box, you can erase everything NOW. I strongly advice you to make a clean start. Clean install makes better to your and computer mental health. You don't have to look into Windows dual-boot related problems in the future.

Comment: Looks like you skipped the part of the dual-boot install instructions where you create space for Ubuntu by reducing the size of your Windows partitions. The easy solution is to redo your install without skipping important steps. If you have any Windows data that you value, a backup is recommended before you begin.

Comment: You can't "merge" unallocated space from two separate drives into one, unless you use LVM.